MSSQL Extremely Slow on Dev Laptop
As the title says, I'm running MSSQL on my development machine and I am having some serious issues with speed. The laptop is an HP and I'm running Windows 11 with SQL Server Developer Edition. I've added some exceptions to Defender (file extensions, the sqlserver process, and the entire sql server directory) but they haven't helped.
When the service first starts everything is fine, but eventually it degrades so bad windows service manager has trouble stopping the process. As it's rolling along queries start to take longer and longer to return. This is true from SSMS and in the web application I'm developing.
I'm not sure what I could be missing.


I'm not sure what I could be missing

memory. a lot of it.
MSSQL is a big mem eater and will eat everything from your machine, and we don't even talk your other dev tool, if visual studio or such that is not the best for memory management too.

I followed your advice and upgraded the RAM in my development machine from 16GB to 32GB but still seeing timeouts. I extended the timeout period in the connection string, but still no dice.

You can try:

Using Task Manager to track and end unnecessary process to free up ram memory when connecting to MSSQL server using SSMS.
Connect to MSSQL using command-line:

Example for SQL Server Authentication:
sqlcmd /S  /d -U -P 

/S = the servername/instance name. Example: Pete's Laptop/SQLSERV  
/d = the database name. Example: Botlek1  
-E = Windows authentication.  
-U = SQL Server authentication/user. Example: Pete  
-P = password that belongs to the user. Example: 1234

